# Put all words that match a criterion to a Map

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm really new at JavaScript and I faced the first issue that I'm trying to solve.

The goal of a program is to use first letter of each word as a key and the unique words as a values.

Here is the code:

```
function sortToMap(str){
    let lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
    let result = lowerString.split(" ");
    let myMap = new Map();

    for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        myMap.set(result[i][0], result[i]);
    }
    return myMap;
}

let myString = "Test string to check How it Works and hopefully it is fine";
console.log(sortToMap(myString));
```

So it looks like this:

(Actual result)

```
Map(8) {
  't' => 'to',
  's' => 'string',
  'c' => 'check',
  'h' => 'hopefully',
  'i' => 'is',
  'w' => 'works',
  'a' => 'and',
  'f' => 'fine'
}
```

(Expected result)

```
Map(8) {
  't' => 'test', 'to',
  's' => 'string',
  'c' => 'check',
  'h' => 'hopefully',
  'i' => 'it', 'is',
  'w' => 'works',
  'a' => 'and',
  'f' => 'fine'
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what can I do to achieve the expected result. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: you are overwriting the value. maybe have an array as the value and add to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value should be an array of words. Check if the map entry exists. If it does, push onto it, otherwise create it.

```js
function sortToMap(str) {
  let lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
  let result = lowerString.split(" ");
  let myMap = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    let initial = result[i][0];
    if (myMap.has(initial)) {
      if (!myMap.get(initial).includes(result[i])) {
        myMap.get(initial).push(result[i]);
      }
    } else {
      myMap.set(initial, [result[i]]);
    }
  }
  return myMap;
}

let myString = "Test string to check How it Works and hopefully it is fine";
console.log(Object.fromEntries(sortToMap(myString)));
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but may I ask another question?

Is there a quick way to make this map to accept only unique values? For example, output looks like 
i: [ 'it', 'it', 'is' ],
with two 'it', but what can I do if I want only one 'it' to make it unique?

Comment: Use `includes()` to test if the array already contains the word. Or use a `Set` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the word as the value, you should create an array that stores all the words starting with a given letter.

Here is a working code :

```js
function sortToMap(str) {
   const words = str.toLowerCase().split(" ")
   // no need for map in JS, an object will work fine
   const map = {}
   for(let word of words) {
      const key = word[0]
      if(!(key in map))
         map[key] = []
      map[key].push(word)
   }
   
   return map
}

let myString = "Test string to check How it Works and hopefully it is fine";
console.log(sortToMap(myString));
```